# How to aggregate and pivot multiple columns in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have following dataframe in R

```
     date        extracted_size     brand    search_spend   search_imp    media    holiday_event
     01-01-2023  1 C                NV       20             10            30       holiday1
     01-01-2023  2 C                NV       10             10            10       holiday1
     02-01-2023  1 C                NV       20             10            30       na
     02-01-2023  2 C                NV       20             10            30       na
     03-01-2023  1 C                NV       20             10            30       holiday2
```

```
df <- structure(list(date = c("01.01.2023", "01.01.2023", "02.01.2023", 
"02.01.2023", "03.01.2023"), extracted_size = c("1 C", "2 C", 
"1 C", "2 C", "1 C"), brand = c("NV", "NV", "NV", "NV", "NV"), 
    search_spend = c(20L, 10L, 20L, 20L, 20L), search_imp = c(10L, 
    10L, 10L, 10L, 10L), media = c(30L, 10L, 30L, 30L, 30L), 
    holiday_event = c("holiday1", "holiday1", "na", "na", "holiday2"
    )), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 5L))
```

```
     cols_to_agg <- c('media')
     cols_to_max <- c('holiday_event')
     cols_to_pivot <- c('search_spend', 'search_imp')
     date_col <- 'date'
```

This is my desired dataframe

```
 date       brand  media search_spend_1_C search_spend_2_C search_imp_1_C search_imp_2_C  holiday_event
 01-01-2023 NV     40    20               10               10             10              holiday1     
 02-01-2023 NV     60    20               20               10             10              na
 03-01-2023 NV     30    20               0                10              0              holiday2
```

Updated dataframe

```
  date = c("01-01-2023", "02-01-2023", "01-01-2023", "03-01-2023", "03-01-2023",
           "05-01-2023", "06-01-2023", "06-01-2023", "08-01-2023", "08-01-2023"),
  extracted_size = c("1 CT", "2 CT", "1 CT", "1 CT", "2 CT",
                     "3 CT", "4 CT", "1 CT", "3 CT", "4 CT"),
  summary = c("NV", "NV", "NV", "NV", "NV",
              "NV", "NV", "NV", "NV", "NV"),
  desc = c("A|CTC", "A|CTC", "A|CTC", "A|CTC", "A|CTC",
           "A|CTC", "A|CTC", "A|CTC", "A|CTC", "A|CTC"),
  search_spend = c(20, 20, 30, 50, 10, 20, 20, 30, 50, 10),
  search_imp = c(30, 30, 10, 10, 10, 30, 30, 10, 10, 10),
  media = c(10, 10, 30, 10, 10, 30, 30, 10, 10, 10),
  media_imp = c(10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 30, 30, 10, 10, 10),
  qty = c(10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 30, 30, 10, 10, 10),
  ratio = c(0.92, 0.88, 0.72, 0.99, 0.82, 0.94, 0.75, 0.96, 1.00, 0.85),
  holiday_event = c("na", "holiday1", "na", "na", "na", "na", "na", "na",
                    "na", "na"),
  holiday_flag = c(0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1))

cols_to_agg <- c('media', 'media_imp', 'qty')
cols_to_max <- c('holiday_event', 'holiday_flag')
cols_to_pivot <- c('search_spend', 'search_imp')
date_col <- 'date'
```

I am doing following in R, but not getting desired results

```
 process_dataframe <- function(df, date_col, cols_to_agg, cols_to_max, cols_to_pivot) {
     df_grouped <- df %>%
     group_by(!!sym(date_col)) %>%
     summarise(across(all_of(cols_to_agg), sum, na.rm = TRUE),
               across(all_of(cols_to_max), max, na.rm = TRUE))


     df_pivot <- df %>%
        group_by(!!sym(date_col)) %>%
        mutate(across(all_of(cols_to_pivot), ~paste0(., "_", extracted_size)))
        pivot_wider(names_from = "extracted_size", values_from = all_of(cols_to_pivot)) 
        rename_with(~paste0(., "_", extracted_size), -!!sym(date_col))

     final_df <- df_grouped %>%
        left_join(df_pivot, by = date_col) %>%

     return(final_df)

}
```

Till summarise it is working, problem is the pivoting the search columns. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @LMc That is already there in the post as desired dataframe

Comment: sorry I missed that!

Comment: You are missing a pipe operator when piping to `pivot_wider`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you are having with your code is due the `id_cols` argument of `pivot_wider` from the documentation:

> Defaults to all columns in data except for the columns specified through names_from and values_from...

All of the columns in your data frame, except `cols_to_pivot` and `extracted_size` are set as `id_cols`. Their unique values identify the rows, which is not what you want or expect. This is the reason in my code below I remove the `cols_to_agg`, which works on your example data.

Additionally,

1. You are missing pipe operators in your `df_pivot` chain, which I am assuming you just left out because you were having trouble with that code chunk.
2. `mutate(across(all_of(cols_to_pivot), ~paste0(., "_", extracted_size)))` is not doing what you are hoping. You are changing the *values* of those columns not the column names. You should review the output of that statement to see what I mean.
3. In your `pivot_wider` statement you have pivoted the column `extracted_size` to the column names, so that column is not available in the data frame you pipe to `rename` so that line will error. Also note, in the tidyverse you do not have to quote it (e.g., `extracted_size` instead of `"extracted_size"`.)

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

pivot_cols <- str_c("^", cols_to_pivot, collapse = "|")
sum_na <- \(x) sum(x, na.rm = T)

df |>
  select(-all_of(cols_to_agg)) |>
  pivot_wider(values_from = all_of(cols_to_pivot),
              names_from = extracted_size,
              names_glue = "{.value}_{gsub(' ', '_', extracted_size)}",
              values_fn = sum_na,
              values_fill = 0L) |>
  left_join(summarize(df, across(all_of(cols_to_agg), sum_na), .by = date_col)) |>
  relocate(matches(pivot_cols), .after = 0)
```

**Output**

```
  date       brand holiday_event media search_spend_1_C search_spend_2_C search_imp_1_C search_imp_2_C
  <chr>      <chr> <chr>         <int>            <int>            <int>          <int>          <int>
1 01.01.2023 NV    holiday1         40               20               10             10             10
2 02.01.2023 NV    na               60               20               20             10             10
3 03.01.2023 NV    holiday2         30               20                0             10              0
```

Comment: I am not clear what you are trying to do with `max` of `cols_to_max` since `holiday_event` is character. Presumably, in your actual data this is numeric. If that is the case then you can simply add your `across(all_of(cols_to_max)....)` statement to the `summarize` statement above.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, can you please explain the steps in your code? and in my case why it was not working? Did I make a mistake in the way variables are accessed inside the function?

Comment: sorry one more this which I have missed is, I want to group by date_col, because when I tried this example on larger dataframe, I can see date duplication across different sizes.

Comment: I have modified your code to include group by, but somehow its not working. I have included groupby ```group_by(across(all_of(date_col))) |>
    select(-all_of(cols_to_agg)) |>``` but its not working. Size of my DF is 520 rows and after aggregation there whould 130 rows since I have 4 different sizes and 130 weeks of unique data

Comment: @Neil do you mind sharing more data the replicates the problem you are having with your full data frame?

Comment: I have updated my question, please check updated dataframe for which the solution is not working. I think its because of column `ratio` which is not being used in any of the aggregations. the length of the dataframe is 10 and after aggregating at `date` level I am expecting 6 rows.

Answer (score 1):

one approach (function body only):

```
df |>
  ## group by all columns except those to agg or max:
  group_by_at(setdiff(names(df), c(cols_to_agg, cols_to_max))) |>
  summarize(across(all_of(cols_to_agg), sum),
            across(all_of(cols_to_max), max)
            ) |> 
  pivot_wider(values_from = all_of(cols_to_pivot),
              names_from = extracted_size,
              names_glue = "{.value}_{gsub(' ', '_', extracted_size)}"
              )
```

```
# A tibble: 4 x 8
# Groups:   date, brand [3]
  date       brand media holiday_event search_spend_1_C search_spend_2_C
  <chr>      <chr> <int> <chr>                    <int>            <int>
1 01.01.2023 NV       30 holiday1                    20               NA
2 01.01.2023 NV       10 holiday1                    NA               10
3 02.01.2023 NV       30 na                          20               20
4 03.01.2023 NV       30 holiday2                    20               NA
# i 2 more variables: search_imp_1_C <int>, search_imp_2_C <int>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I also want it to be aggregated on Date. Please take a look at my desired dataframe